# Using way multi TList in Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, tlist

I want to use multi `TList` in Delphi.  For example:

```
var
 temp1List : TList;
 temp2List : TList;
begin
 temp1List := TList.Create;
 temp2List := TList.Create;
 temp1List.add(temp2List);
end;
```

I think it is not correct because `TList` accepts parameter as `Pointer` value.

Is there way to use multi `TList`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the Generic `TList<T>` instead, eg:

```
uses
  ..., System.Classes, System.Generics.Collections;

var
  temp1List : System.Generics.Collections.TList<System.Classes.TList>;
  temp2List : System.Classes.TList;
begin
  temp1List := System.Generics.Collections.TList<System.Classes.TList>.Create;
  temp2List := System.Classes.TList.Create;
  temp1List.Add(temp2List);
  // don't forget to free them when you are done...
  temp1List.Free;
  temp2List.Free;
end;
```

Alternatively, since `TList` is a class type, you can use `TObjectList<T>` instead, and take advantage of its `OwnsObjects` feature:

```
uses
  ..., System.Classes, System.Generics.Collections;

var
  temp1List : System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList<System.Classes.TList>;
  temp2List : System.Classes.TList;
begin
  temp1List := System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList<System.Classes.TList>.Create; // takes Ownership by default
  temp2List := System.Classes.TList.Create;
  temp1List.Add(temp2List);
  // don't forget to free them when you are done...
  temp1List.Free; // will free temp2List for you
end;
```